# How would one show that any given prime p_i must be a factor of some (p_j - 1)? Is that a true property of primes even?

Tags: prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization

In short, what I'm asking is, if you were to go through the whole set of positive primes term by term and find for each prime p the prime factorization of (p - 1), whether all prime numbers would eventually show up as a factor of some (p_i - 1) term for some i. So the question I suppose can be phrased instead as whether for any prime p_i, there must exist some p_j such that p_i is a factor of (p_j - 1).

Comment: Yes, it is a special case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the comments, [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) implies that, for any prime $p,$ then since $p$ and $(p+1)$ are coprime, there is a prime of the form $p_j= (p+1) + np;\ $ in other words, $ p_j - 1\ $ is a multiple of $p.$ In fact, Dirichlet's theorem implies that there are infinitely many primes in the set $\{ (p+1) + np: n\in\mathbb{N}. \}.$